# Navigating from one Policy to another in PKCE

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I used to be able to navigate from one Policy to another when my app was configure with Implicit Grant.

Now that we have Auth Code Flow + PKCE, I can no longer do it. I get a server error
`AADB2C90088: The provided grant has not been issued for this endpoint. Actual Value : B2C_1A_signup_signin and Expected Value : B2C_1A_signin_facebook`

What I'm trying to do here is

B2C_1A_signup_signin, Combined Signup Signin with Social provider. Here all the links are handled by the orchestration steps.
[image]

If the user clicks on Create Account, then the only way to add "I already have an account" or the Social Providers buttons is to create manually the links with a i.e. Facebook Only policy and copy over the query params.
[image]

Is there a way to mitigate this?

Comment: How did you do it previously? The only supported way is to send the user to the app and reinitialise the auth library with the correct authority and policy id.

Comment: It was working fine with MSAL 1.x and implicit grant. Much like you can go to a Policy directly from the Azure Portal when in Implicit Grant. I read somewhere that since the Code is first used by the signup_signin policy, it cannot be reused for another policy.

Comment: That approach was really not right to begin with. Now with added code challenge as part of PKCE, you need to deep link to your app instead of directly to a B2C policy link, and send the user via MSAL properly to launch the desired policy.

Comment: Ok, is there any way to add a "Already have an account" and all of the social providers on the Create Account page from the policy XMLs?

Comment: No, only the combined sign in and up page has the Social IdPs. Technically this is because you don't sign up with Social, you always Sign in with social. The closest to a sign up with social you can get is, a combined sign in up page, where the username/password fields are hidden.

Comment: We ended up doing the deep link